# Android tethering without using sim card?

Tags: tethering, usb-tethering, router

My Android phone has internet access through WiFi hotspot and it has no sim card inserted. I want to connect this phone to a router via usb or usb-to-rj45-wan-port whatever doable (there is some reason behind that to make the story short).

I can easily accomplish this configuration using PC (i.e., WiFi <--> PC network sharing <--> router), but when I try usb tethering on android it insists to have sim card although it can just use the WiFi connection to provide tethering service. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Which Android device and Android version are you using?

Comment: On a rooted device it should be possible to make this scenario work for sure. Without root it may work or not - depends on the Android versions and the modification the phone manufacturer has made.